# How is a Python class object instance passed to a function? Are class instances in Python pass by reference or pass by value

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, oop, reference

I don't see any questions on SO regarding this, so I would like to ask how a Python class object instance is passed into a function and how it behaves within the function. I have some suspicions from the behaviour I got from running this snippet:

(Note: I understand there are better ways to achieve the same behaviour for this example. My actual use case involves slightly more complicated manouevers: threading etc. I'm just more interested in understanding exactly what is happening with the argument passed.).

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, sound):
        self.name = name
        self.sound = sound

def change_animal(animal_1, animal_2):
    animal_1 = None
    animal_1 = animal_2
    # or better yet,
    # animal_1 = copy.deepcopy(animal_2)

# main
animal_1 = Animal('dog', 'bark')
animal_2 = Animal('duck', 'quack')

change_animal(animal_1, animal_2)
print(animal_1.name)
```

Prints `dog`. I always thought it would change the instance and print `duck`.

Whereas using this:

```
def change_animal(animal_1, animal_2):
    animal_1.name = animal_2.name
    animal_1.sound = animal_2.sound
```

Prints `duck` showing that the instance has been changed?

I wanted to avoid writing anything that requires me to reassign each attribute individually because there is a high likelihood of someone missing a variable and erroneously having a combination of updated and old values.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

In python you need to return the value. When calling the function python is making a copy of your animal_1 object and destroying it after the function ends. If you want to change animal_1 you need to return it as the function result.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, sound):
        self.name = name
        self.sound = sound

def change_animal(animal_1, animal_2):
    animal_1 = deepcopy(animal_2)
    return animal_1

# main
animal_1 = Animal('dog', 'bark')
animal_2 = Animal('duck', 'quack')

animal_1 = change_animal(animal_1, animal_2)
```

The other option is to create the function inside the Animal class.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, sound):
        self.name = name
        self.sound = sound

    def change_animal(self, animal_2):
        self.name = animal_2.name
        self.sound = animal_2.sound

animal_1 = Animal('dog', 'bark')
animal_2 = Animal('duck', 'quack')

animal_1.change_animal(animal_2)
```

Comment: No copy is made. `animal_1` is simply a local variable that refers to the *same* object. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @chepner That's right. Arguments are passed neither by reference nor by value but by assignment. animal_1 in the function is a just local name temporarily 'bound' to the class instance which means that changes can be made to instance attributes but the global name stays bound to the original instance. It can be useful to use `https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=display` to demonstrate what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that in the first example the name doesn't change to `duck` is because of something referred to as [scope of a variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). You can read up more on formalities there, so lets keep it simple here:

Put informally, your first function `change_animal` creates a new variable inside it called `animal_1`. This variable is not visible outside of `change_animal`, and is lost when the function ends.

Your second function `change_animal` indeed takes the animals by reference, and manipulates the objects `animal_1` which is visible in the scope of your script.

If you would want (for any reason) to somehow keep the style of your first `change_animal` function, the example with minimal modifications could look like this:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, sound):
        self.name = name
        self.sound = sound

def change_animal(animal_1, animal_2):
    animal_1 = None
    animal_1 = animal_2
    return animal_1
    # or better yet,
    # animal_1 = copy.deepcopy(animal_2)

# main
animal_1 = Animal('dog', 'bark')
animal_2 = Animal('duck', 'quack')

animal_1 = change_animal(animal_1, animal_2)

print(animal_1.name)
```

Which indeed prints `duck` as you expect.